# Stretching game screen on android to uniform resolution across devices

Tags: c#, android, xna, 2d, monogame

Currently my game fills the screen at the correct aspect ratio for the device using the following code:

In `Initialise()` I have:

```
protected override void Initialize()
{
    graphics.IsFullScreen = true;
    screen_width = graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width;
    screen_height = graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height;
    graphics.SupportedOrientations = DisplayOrientation.LandscapeLeft | DisplayOrientation.LandscapeRight;
    graphics.ApplyChanges();
    base.Initialize();
}
```

In `LoadContent()` I have:

```
protected override void LoadContent()
{
    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
    float screenscale = screen_width / screen_height;
    SpriteScale = Matrix.CreateScale(screenscale, screenscale, 1f);

    //load textures here//
}
```

In `Draw()` I have:

```
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, null, null, null, null, null, SpriteScale);

    //Draw sprites here//

    spriteBatch.End();
    base.Draw(gameTime);
}
```

However, using this code a different amount of game screen is displayed depending on the device width.

How do I get the same amount of game screen to display and scale depending on the device (as shown in the following diagram)?

[image]

EDIT:

In Activity Class I have:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Views;

namespace android_game3
{
    [Activity(Label = "android_game3"
        , MainLauncher = true
        , Icon = "@drawable/icon"
        , Theme = "@style/Theme.Splash"
        , AlwaysRetainTaskState = true
        , LaunchMode = Android.Content.PM.LaunchMode.SingleInstance
        , ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.UserLandscape
        , ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.Keyboard | ConfigChanges.KeyboardHidden | ConfigChanges.ScreenSize)]
    public class Activity1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.AndroidGameActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            var g = new Game1();
            SetContentView((View)g.Services.GetService(typeof(View)));
            g.Run();

            //Hide action bar
            View vw = (View)g.Services.GetService(typeof(View));
            vw.SystemUiVisibility = (StatusBarVisibility)SystemUiFlags.HideNavigation | (StatusBarVisibility)SystemUiFlags.ImmersiveSticky;
            vw.SetOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(new MyUiVisibilityChangeListener(vw));
        }

        //Hide action bar
        private class MyUiVisibilityChangeListener : Java.Lang.Object, View.IOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener
        {
            View targetView;
            public MyUiVisibilityChangeListener(View v)
            {
                targetView = v;
            }
            public void OnSystemUiVisibilityChange(StatusBarVisibility v)
            {
                if (targetView.SystemUiVisibility != ((StatusBarVisibility)SystemUiFlags.HideNavigation | (StatusBarVisibility)SystemUiFlags.Immersive))
                {
                    targetView.SystemUiVisibility = (StatusBarVisibility)SystemUiFlags.HideNavigation | (StatusBarVisibility)SystemUiFlags.ImmersiveSticky;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked my old android project and I used:

```
ScreenWidth = graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth;
ScreenHeight = graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight;
```

Also, how does you activity class look like?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I have added my activity class (see above).

I tried using graphics.PreferredBackBuffer but it doesn't seem to have any impact on the resolution or screen size.

Comment: Can you please explain more about how you used your code?